# Problem using terra::extract results present nan value

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, terra

I would like to extract values from rasters to points. I am using the terra and extract() function.
The script works but I noticed that for some rows (about 100) the result of the extract function is the value "nan".
No points are outside rasters. I have this problem also adding the na.rm=T option.
If I try to do the same operation using as example qgis I don't have this problem.
How is it possible? Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example.  Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you check what's inside those rows calling your raster object like `myRaster[suspected_row, ]`?

Comment: And you're not in something like [poly smaller than raster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182185/terraextract-gives-nan-when-polygon-is-smaller-than-raster-cell), perhaps worth a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by plotting the points (SpatVector `y`) on the raster (SpatRaster `x`)

```
plot(x)
points(y)
```

If that does not look good, you should probably do

```
y <- project(y, crs(x))
```

(perhaps QGIS does that for you?)

Otherwise, to find out where this happens, you could select those points, perhaps like this:

```
e <- extract(x, y, xy=TRUE)
yna <- y[is.na(e[,names(x)[1]]), ]
plot(x)
points(yna)
```

And now zoom in to one or more of these points

```
zoom(x) # click twice on the map
points(yna)
```

You can save these points to disk with `writeVector(yna, "points.shp")` so that you can compare again with QGIS.

And, by the way, `extract` does not have argument `na.rm` (see `?extract`)